# display list item in HTML template

Tags: python, html, django, templates, django-templates

I have 2 list that I imported from my python code to the html template which is called eligable and overTimeHours. I tried displaying them like this:

```
<ul>
{% for item in eligable %}
<div class="pad3">
    <li>{{item}} - {{item.overTimeHours}}</li>
</div>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

but only {{item}} is displayed but {{item.overTimeHours}} did not display.

here is my python code:

```
def specificDate(response):
    empName = employeeName.objects.all
    eligable = []
    overTimeHours = []
    check = False
    if 'checkEmployee' in response.POST:
        n = response.POST.get("nameEmployee")
        specDate = response.POST.get("date")
        correctDate = None
        try:
            newDate = datetime.strptime(specDate,  '%Y-%m-%d')
            correctDate = True
        except ValueError:
            correctDate = False
        print("This One: ",correctDate)
        if correctDate == True:
            if employeeName.objects.filter(employee=n).exists() and Name.objects.filter(date=specDate).exists():
                check = True
                emp = employeeName.objects.get(employee=n)
                t = Name.objects.get(name=emp, date=specDate)
                overT = Name.objects.filter(name=emp, overtime=True)
                for item in overT:
                    eligable.append(item.date)
                    totalTime = (datetime.combine(item.date, item.timeOut)- datetime.combine(item.date, item.timeIn)).seconds/3600
                    hours = int(totalTime)
                    minutes = (totalTime*60) % 60
                    seconds = (totalTime*3600) % 60
                    time = "%d:%02d:%02d" % (hours, minutes, seconds) 
                    overTimeHours.append(time)
                checkIn = t.timeIn.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
                checkOut = t.timeOut.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
                messages.info(response, checkIn + ' - ' + checkOut)
                return render(response, "main/specificDate.html",  context={"empName":empName, "eligable":eligable, "check":check, "overTimeHours":overTimeHours})
            else:
                messages.info(response, 'Result does not exist')
        else:
            messages.info(response, 'Please enter correct input')
    else: 
        pass
    return render(response, "main/specificDate.html",  {"empName":empName})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the above code, **eligable** and **overTimeHours** are two different lists. The variable you are displaying is 'item' which is an element of **eligable** and not of **overTimeHours** and vice versa.

There will be two 'for loops', one for **eligable** and another for **overTimeHours**, if you want to display items from both the lists.